# ADT Circular Queue enqueue and dequeue

Tags: c

```
#define SIZE 5
struct queue{   float data[SIZE];
                int head,tail;
};

void init(struct queue *q){ q->head=0; q->tail=SIZE-1; }
int  empty(struct queue *q){
    int temp=q->tail+1;
    if(temp==SIZE) temp=0;
    return temp==q->head;
}
int  full(struct queue *q){
    int temp=q->tail+2;
    //if(temp==SIZE) temp=0;
    //if(temp==SIZE+1) temp=1;
    if(temp>=SIZE) temp-=SIZE;
    return temp==q->head;
}
void enqueue(struct queue *q, float item){
    if(++q->tail>=SIZE) q->tail-=SIZE;
    q->data[q->tail]=item;
}
float dequeue(struct queue *q){
    float temp= q->data[q->head];
    if(++q->head>=SIZE) q->head-=SIZE;
    return temp;
}
```

above code was given by my professor and I am having trouble with understanding enqueue function `if(++q->tail>=SIZE) q->tail-=SIZE;` part and dequeue function `if(++q->head>=SIZE) q->head-=SIZE;` why i need to evaluate those conditions? someone please explain to me in details... thanks

Comment: Because the queue is circular. It has `SIZE` number of entries, so you cannot increment the `head` and `tail` indexes forever. You have to use `SIZE` as modulo in order to "circulate" those indexes.

Comment: BTW, you professor might as well have used `if(++q->head==SIZE) q->head=0;` (and the same with `tail`). Those indexes can become larger than `SIZE` only if you're using this code within a multi-threaded application, and I doubt that this is the intention here because there would be much bigger problems if it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you an example :

See this image :
[Enqueue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNl86.png)
(I can't post image here due to reputation points, So, giving the link)

Now,
In fig.1 :

head=0, tail=3

So, first we need to check if `tail==size-1`. But it is not the case with fig. 1, so, we just need to increment tail and store new item at that position.

In fig. 2:

head=2, tail=7

So, first we need to check if `tail==size-1`. So, we will increment the tail and then subtract the `size` from it to get `tail=0`.

Summarizing this steps, we need to increment `tail` and check `tail==size-1` and if it is true we need to do `tail=tail-size`. So, what we your code does is, combining steps increment and check. So, it checks the incremented value of `tail` with `size` by statement `++q->tail>=size`. If it is true, then subtract `size` from `tail`.

Here `++q->tail` happens irrespective of the condition is true or false.

Just in case if you are new to C language, you can go for this alternative in enquque :

```
++q->tail;    // or q->tail=q->tail+1 or q->tail+=1;
if(q->tail==size)
    q->tail=q->tail-size;
q->data[q->tail]=item;
```

Same can be explained for Dequeue with head.

Comment: "Summarizing this steps, we need to increment tail and check tail==size-1", should be tail==size

Comment: great explanation . now i understand both enqueue and dequeue

Answer (score 0):

Queue is circular. When you try to enqueue an item

```
void enqueue(struct queue *q, float item){
    if(++q->tail>=SIZE) q->tail-=SIZE;
    q->data[q->tail]=item;
}
```

and the tail of the queue would reach the SIZEth element ( theoretical element at index of one past the end of the queue), the queue is designed to wrap and overwrite items from the begin of the queue.

Comment: rather than my professor enqueue function,can you suggest me any other enqueue functions(less complex ones) that i can use ?

Comment: @Mike this function is not complex, it is just one insertion most of the time, and just one subtraction and one insertion in case we are at the end of the queue

Answer (score 0):

This method can be applied to other problems as well.
Fist you should have or get some idea of what the code should do.
In this particular problem we are dealing with a circular queue which means that
some things (numbers) are standing in a limited size queue with first to leave is in the head of it and the last to arrive is in the tail.

The circular queue is 'circular' because the "waiting spot" of head and tail are constantly changing while the maximum size of the queue remains constant.
The idea is that you don't move items in the queue (like people in a queue) what you just mark the first and last items in that queue and keep the order

To properly understand what those statements do you should first attempt to
expand the compound statements.

`if(++q->tail>=SIZE) q->tail-=SIZE;`

According to the [this table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)
it means:

```
++q->tail /* we have a new arrival, tail is always the index of the last to come-in*/
/* lets say that the previous arrival was placed in q->data[4], the last element of the array, where we should put the new one? q->tail is now 5 but data[5] is out of bounds */
if((q->tail) >= SIZE) /* we increased the index but we have limited space in the array*/       
   /* this is the "circular" part. for size=5 it means that tail 
      was over the limit and should do the circle back to 0 to 
      make space for the new arrival */
   q->tail -= SIZE;
```

Try to wrap your head around the dequeue by yourself. Use precedence rules to unpack the statement into several.